# Is there a MooTools version of the jQuery "timeago" plugin?

Tags: javascript, mootools, timeago

I'm looking for a small MooTools library that does about what the plugin linked below does, i.e. dynamically update timestamps on a web page every minute or so to say "a minute ago", "2 hours ago" etc., maybe with graceful fallback for browsers with JavaScript disabled.

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Don't feel like writing it myself now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own *timeago* code which basically uses MooTools More *Date.Extras* `Date.timeDiffInWords()` like this in pseudo-JS (you can wrap it into a class, which I did but cannot release):

```
function update(element) {
     enhance(element); // Enhances all new elements; skips already enhanced elements
     var time = getTime(element); // Yields the time as a Date object
     element.set('text', time.timeDiffInWords());
}

function updateAll() {
    var i;
    var elements = $$('abbr.timeago');
    if ( !elements )
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        update(elements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes and it's even better :) in mootools more they have put a Date.Extras class

[http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date.Extras#Date:timeDiff](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date.Extras#Date%3atimeDiff)

Comment: Well, that is apparently just for dates that you want to convert. What I meant is something that uses this stuff to dynamically and automatically update dates being shown on a page, e.g. for all elements with a CSS class "timeago". Might have to write it myself though then :-(

Comment: A few more lines to make it generic and unsuitable for the underhanded scripting contest.